# What is the path of the Android DCIM Folder ??i want to get android camera gallery folder path to delete images and videos?

Tags: java, android

```
{

        File file = new File("DCIM\*");// here i am going to add the path so the folder..

        if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");

        }
```

This is going to delete all the images and the videos in the folder.

Comment: @user2818864-see this link helps u -http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

Comment: String folder = "/sdcard/DCIM";

Comment: Thanks kosh and Farha..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


or like this 

String directoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "/";
```

Comment: Thanks Faraha.. i have set location but images and videos are not deleted .. dont getting whats the issue

Comment: Sanket i have tried the code that you have edited but its also not deleting the images